# Extracting out the Fourier modes of a series, and using these to reconstruct data series

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I would like to extract the most important frequency modes from a data set which exhibits strong annual periodicity, as well as some (less) important shorter-term frequency components. The following approximates the data series fairly well:

```
n = 3*365;
data = If[# < 0.3, 0, #] & /@ MovingAverage[1.6 #^2 & /@ (Table[Sin[ \[Pi] x/365], {x, n}] + 
   RandomReal[{0.5, -0.5}, {n}]), 20];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

Generating:

[image]

I have tried taking the discrete Fourier transform of the data, and then looking at its absolute value to identify the most important frequency components using:

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[data]]]
```

However, I am having trouble 'seeing', then extracting, the most important components, which I hope should correspond to the annual periodicity, as well as some shorter-term components, of perhaps a few months in period.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I know this probably as much to do with my lack of knowledge about Fourier series, as it is about my Mathematica inexperience!

**Update:** to be clear, I would like to extract the most important modes, then reconstruct the data series using only these few.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Try `Periodogram`.

Answer (score 3):

To use Fourier, subtract out the mean (otherwise the "DC" component swamps out the period you are trying to see).

```
q = data - Mean[data];
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[q]][[1 ;; 20]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I only plotted the first few terms so it would be easier to see the low frequency region. What you see here is a large peak in the 4th bin (the first is DC, the second is one oscillation across the data set, etc.) So the peak at 4 represents a fundamental periodicity of 3 oscillations across the data set. Since your data set is 3*365 long, this is one oscillation per 365 samples.

If you wish to go a little deeper, you can reconstruct the signal using variable numbers of Fourier parameters. Here is a Manipulate that demonstrates (make sure to define the `data` sequence first). The heart of this is the line `rec` which builds an approximation to the data signal using the magnitude and phase of the Fourier coefficients and the `Cos` at the appropriate frequencies.

```
Manipulate[Module[{}, sig = data - Mean[data]; lenSig = Length[sig];
  fftY = Fourier[sig, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
  mag = Abs[fftY]/lenSig; phase = Arg[fftY];
  ordMag = Ordering[mag, All, GreaterEqual];
  rec = Total[Table[mag[[ordMag[[k]]]] Cos[2 Pi (ordMag[[k]] - 1) (n - 1)/lenSig + 
        phase[[ordMag[[k]]]]], {k, 1, numTerms}, {n, 1, lenSig}]];
  GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[{Tooltip[mag, "not used"], 
      Tooltip[Thread[{ordMag[[1 ;; numTerms]], 
         mag[[ordMag[[1 ;; numTerms]]]]}], "used in reconstruction"]},
      Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Fourier Transform of Signal", 
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Black, PointSize[0.015]}}], 
    ListLinePlot[{Tooltip[sig, "signal"], 
      Tooltip[rec, "reconstruction"]}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Signal (blue) and Reconstructed Signal (brown)", 
      PlotRange -> All, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]}, ImageSize -> 800]], 
   {{numTerms, 1, "number of terms in reconstruction"}, 1, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great - thanks for that. Can I ask how I can then go about extracting the Fourier coefficients, for the most important few modes, then reconstructing the series using these? Sorry for my lack of knowledge here!

Comment: That's great; many thanks for your help here. I really appreciate the time taken for you to make such an in-depth response; particularly one that allows me to dynamically look at the answer. Best, Ben